# ActiveRecord - find records that its association count is 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

In my Ruby on Rails app I have the following model:

```
class SlideGroup < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :survey_group_lists, foreign_key: 'group_id'
  has_many :surveys, through: :survey_group_lists
end
```

I want to find all orphaned slide groups. Orphaned slide group is slide group which is not connected to any survey. I've been trying following query but it does not return anything and I'm sure that I have orphaned records in my test database:

```
SlideGroup.joins(:surveys).group("slide_groups.id, surveys.id").having("count(surveys.id) = ?",0)
```

this generates following sql query:

```
SlideGroup Load (9.3ms)  SELECT "slide_groups".* FROM "slide_groups" INNER JOIN "survey_group_lists" ON "survey_group_lists"."group_id" = "slide_groups"."id" INNER JOIN "surveys" ON "surveys"."id" = "survey_group_lists"."survey_id" GROUP BY slide_groups.id, surveys.id HAVING (count(surveys.id) = 0)
```

Comment: You need an `outer join` here, since `inner join` won’t return orphans.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're using [`joins`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-joins), which is `INNER JOIN`, whereas what you need is an `OUTER JOIN` -
 [`includes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-includes):

```
SlideGroup.includes(:surveys).group("slide_groups.id, surveys.id").having("count(surveys.id) = ?",0)
```

A bit cleaner query:

```
SlideGroup.includes(:surveys).where(surveys: { id: nil })
```

Comment: Rails 5 has also added a `left_outer_joins` method -- https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/12071

Answer (score 1):

Finding orphan records has been explained by others.

I see problems with this approach:

- There should not be any orphan in the first place
- The presence of a `survey.id` does not guarantee the presence of a `Survey`
- What about `SurveyGroupList` that are orphan?

So the proper solution would be to ensure that no orphans are left in the DB. By implementing the proper logic **AND** adding foreign keys with *on delete cascade* to the DB. You can also add `dependent: :destroy` option to your associations but this only works if you use `#destroy` on your models (not `delete`) and of course does not work if you delete directly via SQL.